# Permission denied to create migration folder in Django app in vagrant

Tags: python, django, vagrant, django-migrations

I am trying to upgrade to `Django 1.8` from `1.4`

I tried to run the following command in vagrant environment

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations [app_name]
```

and got this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 9, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/srv/www/[project]/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 338, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/srv/www/[project]/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 330, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/srv/www/[project/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 390, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/srv/www/[project]/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 441, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/srv/www/[project]/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py",
>   line 143, in handle
>       self.write_migration_files(changes)   File "/srv/www/[project]/shared/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py",
>   line 165, in write_migration_files
>       os.mkdir(migrations_directory) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/vagrant/code/[project]/[app]/migrations'

Ran the command after logging into the app via vagrant ssh [app] command. 
Then setup the virtual env and then this happens.

Comment: try :
 sudo python manage.py makemigrations [app_name]

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use sudo or be root to make the migrations work.

*I think sorl.thumbnail was trying to write it's migrations to a protected folder (Python site-packages perhaps?) which made things not very portable.*

So to overcome the issue first create a directory in your project called "sorl_thumbnail" then include a blank __init __.py file.

```
MyProject
|_MyApp1
| |_migrations
| |___init__.py
|
|_sorl_thumbnail
  |___init__.py
```

finally add these lines somewhere in settings.py:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'thumbnail': 'sorl_thumbnail.migrations',
}
```

Thats it!

Now you should be able to run:

```
makemigrations thumbnail
migrate thumbnail
```

The migrations should now be found in your local project's "*sorl_thumbnail/migrations*" folder.

Answer (score 0):

you should be login as admin or root to your computer. If you not sure, try using sudo command on your console/terminal:

sudo python manage.py makemigrations [app_name]